# проблема с кастом между ViewController' ом

Tags: swift

Суть такая пытаюсь добавить возможность редактирования с одного ViewController на другой. Но при попытке это сделать компилятор вот так вот ругается "Could not cast value of type 'EmojiReader.NewEmojiTableViewController' (0x10993f688) to 'UINavigationController' (0x7fff86f31638)". Не пойму чем ему не понравилась строка  let navigationVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

Иерархия выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    guard segue.identifier == "editEmojiScreen" else { return }
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let emoji = objects[indexPath.row]
    let navigationVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let newEmojiVC = navigationVC.topViewController as! NewEmojiTableViewController
    newEmojiVC.emoji = emoji
    newEmojiVC.title = "Edit"
}
```

Comment: Картинка очень размытая, ничего не видно

Comment: @schmidt9 да там просто понимать иерархию что между одним view и другим находить uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Там 2 перехода, второй для чего и какой у него identifier? Оставьте один переход, через nc. У вас похоже кастуется не тот переход.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev второй переход для сохранение и добавления на 1 viewController новой ячейки а segue у него «saveSegue» для редактирования «editEmojiScreen»

Comment: @OlegSoloviev просто если я уберу переход сохранения и добавления ячейки на новый экран работы не будет как я понял

Answer (score 1):

у вас видимо класс UINavigationController не унаследован от UINavigationController к которому вы хотите привести

Comment: а как его заставить это делать? просто как обычно у препода в уроке все ок, у меня нет. я как бы нашёл решения но с визуально точки зрения меня это не очень устраивает

Answer (score 0):

Решение было просто, оказывается скасить он не могу, так как данный segue уже был виден в NewEmojiTableViewController без дополнительного перехода на UINavigationController (почему в данном swift 5.3 эта работает так не понятно, как было раньше не работает, хотя выглядит довольно логично) теперь код выглядит так

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    guard segue.identifier == "editEmoji" else { return }
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let emoji = objects[indexPath.row]
    let navigationVC = segue.destination as! NewEmojiTableViewController
    navigationVC.emoji = emoji
    navigationVC.title = "Edit"
}
```

Правда экран работает не много не так как хотелось (должен по типу present modally, а он открывается на новом экране)